# Transform rotation based on the "Minutes" (Unity 3D)

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

- At X minutes (say 360 mins) angle of gameobject is 0 degrees.
- At Y minutes (say 1200 mins) angle of gameobject should reach 180
  degrees.

My question is, what is the angle for each minute (X -> Y), so the gameobject updates its rotation based on the angle from the result, each minute.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question is about algebra, rather than programming.

Comment: Questions which are in the category "this question is about algebra, rather than programming" should be closed, please please help reduce clutter on the Unity3D tag by clicking to close such questions.

Comment: Just ask for sample code showing current efforts. If none is given, close away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not that difficult. You can easily find the distribution. Lets take actual duration which is `1200 - 360 = 840`.

Actually the maths you can apply for such kind of problems is like,

```
X * 840 = 180
```

X will be the value which will multiplied `840` times to get the value of `180`.

```
X = 180/840 => X = 0.214285
```

That'd be the per minute degree change in order to get 180 degrees in 840 minutes.

So you'd change the angle by `0.214285` degrees per minute in order to get it. :)

Similarly apply the same formula for any duration like, from 1000 to 1200, you can do it as,

```
1200-1000 = 200

180/200 = 0.9
```

So the new change in angle required per minute is `0.9`.

Comment: Above minutes (X & Y) are calculated using System.DateTime, like min and max. What if user launches the app at Z mins (say 1000 mins), what will be the rotation of the object.

Comment: Still want 180 degrees at 1200? Or want to keep the same distribution?

Comment: Yeah at 1200 min object should be at 180.

Comment: I did change some mathematics as previous one was not accurate..

Comment: @RevanthPrasad You should show effort - currently you look like a programmer who cannot do elementary math :-/

Comment: @HamzaHasan I did not downvote your answer.  I do not know why you think I did.'

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Your timings were weird :|

Comment: @HamzaHasan Don't draw such conclusions.  Experienced programmers know why.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen my apologies

Comment: Yeah I know it is elementary maths, sometimes simple things might confuse us. Sorry for going against rules .